# file system needed

Tags: partitioning, disk

I have a 1 Tegabype hard drive formatted as NTFS running MS Windows Vista Ultimate 32 Bit. I created a 26 Gig partition D: using a partition program and it is formatted as NTFS.  When I boot off of my Ubuntu Linux 14 disk and select the D: partition it says no root system defined.  I do not know how to fix this for installing linux.  I could use the option to install beside Windows but it only offered to create a partition on my 500 gig external backup hard drive.  When I was running Linux 11 it could be installed within Windows you create a dual boot system setup and could be removed through Windows uninstall program.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use manual partitioning during installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation)

Answer (score 0):

Below are the steps for manual partitioning.  Note that Linux uses the EXT3/EXT4 file system, not NTFS, though this is something you can fix through the installer.

1. In the installer, right click on the partition where you want to install Ubuntu and select "configure" (or something similar)
2. Choose ext3 or ext4 as the file system
3. Under the "use as" drop-down, select "/".
4. Check the box next to "Format?" so the installer will automatically convert the partition from the NTFS file system to EXT3/EXT4.

Note that a swap partition is typically recommended, so I would recommend creating another partition (~4 GB or so) to use as swap.  Linux uses swap space in case the computer runs out of RAM.  To set up the swap partition:

1. Right click the partition you want to use as swap and select "configure"
2. Choose "swap" from the Format drop-down
3. Choose "swap" from the Use as drop-down
4. Check the box next to "Format"

As you mention there used to be an option to install Ubuntu within Windows (through a program called WUBI), but unfortunately WUBI has been discontinued since Ubuntu 12.04.